# How do you pass the keystroke event in a $.bind method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure how to pass the specific keystroke through the bind method..

```
$(document).bind('keyup', event, keyup_handler(event));
```

This is my lucky failing guess..

This is the method it gets passed too..

```
var keyup_handler = function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    close_lightbox();
    return false;       
  };
};
```

Another failing variation :

```
    var keyup_handler = function(e){
      if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        close_lightbox();
        return false;       
      };
    };

$(document).bind('keyup', keyup_handler(e));
```

Which returns:

```
 e is not defined
```

Comment: Did you try `$(document).bind('keyup', keyup_handler);`? And I recommend `e.which` instead of `e.keyCode`.

Comment: Yah it doesn't know what event or e means.

Comment: Why is e.keyCode better?

Comment: I added an example to the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might misunderstand the [`bind`](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=bind) API.

With your code, you're telling jQuery to bind `undefined` to `keyup`:

- You immediately invoke `keyup_handler` by writing `keyup_handler(...)`.  It returns `undefined`, which is what is passed to the jQuery `bind` call.
- The second argument (`event`) is also undefined.

Instead,

```
$(document).bind('keyup', keyup_handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your second example here:

```
var keyup_handler = function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    close_lightbox();
    return false;       
  };
};

$(document).bind('keyup', keyup_handler);​
```

When you call `bind`, you are passing it a function to call internally.  Bind will call the function, passing it the event object by default.

The code that you tried was running keyup_handler() and passing the results to `bind`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and you'll see.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>jQuery Keyup Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var keyup_handler = function(e) {
        if (e.which == 27) {
            alert('ESCAPE');
            return false;
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).bind('keyup',keyup_handler);
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>Press the escape key.
</body>
</html>
```